# QGIS GDAL toolbox - can't edit console call

Tags: qgis, gdal

I've noticed a few answers for QGIS/GDAL questions that show how one can edit the console call e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/159577/76240

Im using QGIS Essen 2.14.3 via OSGeo4W on Windows 7, and I can't see the pencil button indicated so I'm stuck editing a call in notepad and pasting it into the OSgeo4w shell.

Is there an option somewhere I need to change to enable in-tool editing? Has the option simply been removed?

[image: screenshot of gdal tool window]

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Sure, added @EyeMando

Comment: Mr Andrew Jeffry, I also tried using the method that you have suggested. It does not work anymore. Do you know another method?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152943)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/152943)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you are running it from the processing toolbox. Don't know why it happens, but it happens for me too.

Try going: Raster (menu at top of the screen) > Projections > Warp

You should see the pencil button and be able to edit the GDAL code

Comment: Huh. Well, that's annoying. Thanks though!

Comment: Its weird behaviour, I thought the processing toolbox was just an entry point to the existing tools. Maybe a QGIS dev or someone close to the project can provide an explanation as to whats happening.

Comment: There is an open ticket for it: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/11323, but no progress yet in current QGIS-dev 2.15.